# ServiceStack RequiredRole is not asking for role to access

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to define a permissions for a ServiceStack Service which only can access the Admin Role for example and I have this Service with the RequireRole attribute but it seems does not work because I can access the service as a USER .

```
[Authenticate]
[RequiredRole("Admin")]
public class HelloService : Service
{
    public const string HelloServiceCounterKey = "HelloServiceCounter";

    public object Any(HelloRequest request)
    {
            var userSession = SessionAs<AppHost.CustomUserSession>();
            Session.Set(HelloServiceCounterKey, Session.Get<int>(HelloServiceCounterKey) + 1);
            var roles = string.Join(", ", userSession.Roles.ToArray());
            return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + request.Name + ", your role(s): " + roles };

    }
}
```

AccountController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("Admin"))
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("admin", "abc");

                var authService = AppHostBase.Resolve<AuthService>();
                authService.RequestContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ToRequestContext();
                var response = authService.Authenticate(new Auth
                                                            {
                                                                UserName = model.UserName,
                                                                Password = model.Password,
                                                                RememberMe = model.RememberMe
                                                            });

                // add ASP.NET auth cookie
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            catch (HttpError)
            {
            }
        }
```

and Here's my AppHost.cs

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {

        /*Register storage for User Session */
        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient()); /*Tipo Base de MemoryCacheClient es ICacheClient*/
        container.Register<ISessionFactory>(c => new SessionFactory(c.Resolve<ICacheClient>())); /*Tipo Base de SessionFactory es ISessionFactory*/


        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
           () => new CustomUserSession(),
           new[] { new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider() }
       ));

        Plugins.Add(new SessionFeature());

        Routes
          .Add<HelloService>("/hello")
          .Add<HelloService>("/hello/{Name*}");

        //Set JSON web services to return idiomatic JSON camelCase properties
        ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;

        container.Register(new TodoRepository());           

        //Set MVC to use the same Funq IOC as ServiceStack
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));
    }
```

Comment: Did you registered the authentication provider correctly in app host?

Comment: this way is correctly? _italic_ **bold** `Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
               () => new CustomUserSession(),
               new[] { new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider() }
           ));` @Prashant Lakhlani

Comment: Yes, that looks correct, can you paste your apphost code?

Comment: I already paste edit and paste the AppHost.cs hope you can help me!@Prashant Lakhlani

Answer (score 0):

The [wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) states:

> As with Authenticate, you can mark services (instead of DTO) with
>   RequiredPermission attribute, too.

It does NOT state whether you can use the RequiredRole attribute with a service, so I think you cannot and looking at the comments in [source](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/RequiredRoleAttribute.cs) it does seem to target just requestDTO object.

Comment: (I also wish you could use it on any method).

Comment: You can attribute a Service, the issue here is that calling the service directly in code does not apply the Request filters as it's just a direct C# method call.